# Firebird SQL: Check if notNULL constraint is set for a specific column?

Tags: sql, firebird, nullable, constraints

I want my C# program to know if the notNULL constraint is set for a specific Firebird database column. Can it be checked dynamically, perhaps by querying the meta data? I find the Firebird documentation to be very sparse.

Also, how does Firebird provide information what columns exist in a specific table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it manually, use the following statement:

```
select rdb$null_flag
from rdb$relation_fields
where rdb$relation_name = 'MyTable' and rdb$field_name = 'MyField'
```

Alternatively you may try exploring `FbDataReader.GetSchemaTable()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request the Firebird metadata for the constraints;
all information describing them is stored in system tables.
For an example on how to do that see the “List CONSTRAINTs”
section on the following page:
http://www.alberton.info/firebird_sql_meta_info.html.

Comment: The information in the link is good, however your answer would be much better if you copied the parts about `NULL` constraints and getting table columns into it. That would be in the spirit of SO, which aims to be more than a collection of (possibly outdated) links.